# Armazenar dados de um formulário

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como faço para armazenar dados de um formularia, vai ter um apresentação no curso e gostaria que as pessoas que acessarem minha pagina deixassem um comentário sobre o que acharam... Queria saber se isso é possível apenas com JavaScript, os comentários poderiam ser armazenados em um documento de Texto... Não sei como isso funciona. 
Minha estrutura HTML

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css"> 
    body{ 
        background: white;
        url("comentario/fundocomentario.jpg") top left repeat-x fixed; 
    }
    </style>

    <img src="comentario/deixeseucomentario.png" width=500 height=100>
    <font size=5 color="black" face="Broadway">

    <font size=4 color="#8B0000" face="Broadway">
    <form name="cadastro">
        <img src="comentario/comentarionome.png" width=50 height=25>

        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" maxlength=30 size=50 style="background-color:#98F5FF;color:#8B0000;font-size:15px">
        <br>
        <img src="comentario/comentarioemail.png" width=50 height=25>

        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength=30 size=49 style="background-color:#98F5FF;color:#8B0000;font-size:15px">
        <br>
        </font>
        <font size=4 color="black" face="Broadway"><br>

        <img src="comentario/achou.png" width=350 height=40>
        <br>

        <textarea id="comentario" name="comentario" cols=62 rows=5 style="background-color:#98F5FF;color:#8B0000;font-size:15px">
        </textarea>

        <input type="button" value="salvar" src="salvar" onclick="salvar()">

        <iframe id="conteudo" style="display: none"></iframe>

    </form>

<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="comentario/comentariocentro.png" width=400 height=40>

</html>
```

Comment: Um exemplo básico em php :

<?php

$texto = $_POST['input_texto'];

// Abre ou cria o arquivo bloco1.txt
// "a" representa que o arquivo é aberto para ser escrito
$fp = fopen("bloco1.txt", "a");
 
// Escreve o que foi retirado do 'input_texto' no bloco1.txt
$escreve = fwrite($fp, $texto);
 
// Fecha o arquivo
fclose($fp); -> OK
?>

Comment: Com javascript é possível, porém os dados seriam salvos apenas na máquina local do usuário. Ou seja, seria útil pra você apenas se todos os usuários se cadastrassem na mesma máquina. Caso contrário cada cadastro ficaria em um máquina.

Comment: No caso seria um computador para cada grupo... Vou tentar usar em php dps. Obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: Podes explicar melhor com queres integrar esses dados? Os utilizadores podiam enviar esse formulário para um servidor e guardares numa bd ou ficheiro.

Comment: Seria somente um local para as pessoas que acessarem a pagina poderem interagir e comentarem sobre o que acharam... Nome, e comentário apenas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo completo de como você pode salvar os arquivos em txt e depois fazer a leitura dos mesmos.

Salve em um arquivo html e faça o teste.

```js
function saveTextAsFile() {
  var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  if (window.webkitURL != null) {
    // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
    // without actually adding it to the DOM.
    downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
  } else {
    // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
    // before it can be clicked.
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  }

  downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function loadFileAsText() {
  var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
    var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
    document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
  };
  fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Text to Save:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <textarea id="inputTextToSave" style="width:512px;height:256px"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
      <td>
        <input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="file" id="fileToLoad">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button>
        <td>
    </tr>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

[Como Salvar e carregar arquivos de texto usando html5 e javascript - ENG](http://aspdotnetuncle.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/loading-editing-and-saving-text-file-in.html)

Comment: Seria bacana se você incluísse a fonte de onde você copiou esse código.

Comment: Valeeeu, ajudou muito!

Comment: @Karina, se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, marque ela como  resposta aceita.

Comment: Ok! Só mais uma pergunta... No caso, é possível o botão de Salvar ter duas funções? Salvar o aquivo e direcionar para uma pagina html?

Comment: claro e so colocar a função para redirecionar no final da função `saveTextAsFile` , uma forma de redirecionar seria assim `window.location.href = 'index.html';`.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo validar esse formulário ;/ Como faço para exibir um alert se caso a pessoa não tiver preenchido o textarea e um alert de que o comentário foi salvo?

Comment: @Karina para novas dúvidas você deve abrir uma nova pergunta.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87141/validar-um-formulario

Comment: Boa noite. Funcionou mesmo, mas faltou o <script> e o </script> no trecho com as funções chamadas pelo html. Pode ser óbvio para os mais experts, mas como estou começando, o código inicialmente não funcionou, mas descobri depois. Mas muito obrigado. O exemplo me ajudou bastante. Valeu.

Comment: Agora entendi o porque. Os caracteres especiais não aparecem aqui. Me referia ao " script" e "barra script" no inicio e fim das funções.

Answer (score -2):

Olá,
Pelo o que vi, seria mais fácil por PHP, salvando em uma base de dados.

O código seria mais ou menos o seguinte:

```
<?php
include_once('conexao.php');
if(isset($_POST['comentar'])) {
    $sql_code = "INSERT INTO nome_da_tabela (nome, comentario) SET ('$_POST[nome]', '$_POST[comentario]')"; //Aqui seria o código SQL inserindo um registro no banco de dados
    $sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_code);
}
$sql_code1 = "SELECT * FROM nome_da_tabela"; //Aqui tem mais um código SQL, porém aqui é para ter todos os comentários registrados na tabela.
$sql_query1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_code1);
$row = $sql_query1->fetch_assoc();
echo '<table><thead><tr><th>Nome</th><th>Comentário</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
do {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['nome'].'</td><tr>'.$row['comentario'].'</tr></tr>'
}while($row = $sql_query->fetch_assoc())
echo '</tbody></table>'
?>
```